# Multiple field in Journey Salesforce Task

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Hi I would like to append 2 fields in a description field [as per the screenshot you can only select once a time]. Probably he is changing manually the {{Event}} and adding two fields there where it's being added to the flow but then this is not working. I suppose this is working as expected selecting only one field right ? Would there be a workaround to add multiple selection of fields using the moustache code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field on the left is a regular text field, so you can do the following:

- copy the moustached variable
- select the next value from the attribute list and paste the copied value alongside it in the configuration field on the left
- separate the moustached codes with something so they're more readable like `/` or even hard-code some comments
- repeat for any other values you would need

You can even reuse the copied attributes in other parts of the journey - copying those values is actually the only way right now to dynamically push data unique to a customer in the Update Block activity.